# How to specify multiple topics in youtube search API?

Tags: youtube-api

Can I only give one topic id to search youtube videos ?
Is there a way I can give more than one parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

We just rolled out support for [additional video topics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#topicDetails.relevantTopicIds%5B%5D) that are "relevant" to the video, but don't completely describe the video:

As of right now, you can just specify a single topic id to use as a search filter, but these additional topics (as well as the fact that a video can have more than a single "central" topic) do imply that providing combinations of topic ids as a filter would be useful.

Could you please [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) to keep track of this publicly off of Stack Overflow?